# Dynamic (programmaticaly) ItemTemplate (DataTemplate) in Silverlight?

Tags: c#, silverlight, silverlight-3.0, datatemplate, itemtemplate

I have this code:

```
      <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
   <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="900" Width="1200">
   <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="300"></RowDefinition>
            <RowDefinition Height="200"></RowDefinition>
            <RowDefinition Height="200"></RowDefinition>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="300"></ColumnDefinition>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="300"></ColumnDefinition>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="300"></ColumnDefinition>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="300"></ColumnDefinition>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <ListBox x:Name="lst1" Width="300" Height="100" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0">
                <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="3">
                            <TextBlock Text="Id:" Foreground="Brown"></TextBlock>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Id}" Foreground="Blue"></TextBlock>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
  </ListBox>
  <ListBox x:Name="lst1" Width="300" Height="100" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1"/>
  <ListBox x:Name="lst2" Width="300" Height="100" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2"/>
  <ListBox x:Name="lst3" Width="300" Height="100" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="3"/>
  </Grid>
    </Grid>
```

How can I create a DataTemplate/ItemTemplate in the code behind with Silverlight?

Answer (score 0):

To create a `DataTemplate` dynamically you need to build the Xaml string that describes it using XML manipulation objects such as `XDocument` or `XmlTextWriter`.  The root of this Xaml needs to be the `DataTemplate` itself (remember to include or the correct namespaces).

You can then pass the resulting string `XamlReader.Load` which will create the `DataTemplate` which you then assign to the `ItemTemplate` property of the `ListBox`.